# Magento Ajax cart On delete redirect to Delete page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento-1.9

When I want to delete more than 1 product one by one from AJAX Cart , for 1st product its working fine but when I try to delete the another product the page it redirect to delete page URL like 
`(SiteURL/checkout/cart/delete/id/012/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyMi)`

and showing some json or html data like    `{"message":"Item was removed.","update_blocks":[{"key":".header .links","value":"<div class=\"links\"> ....`

Delete Item From Shopping cart function deleteAction()

```
public function deleteAction() {
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                        ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxcart/response');
                $_response->setError(true);
                $_response->setMessage($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
                $_response->send();
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxcart/response');
        $_response->setMessage($this->__('Item was removed.'));
        //append updated blocks
        $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('ajaxcart');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $_response->addUpdatedBlocks($_response);
        $_response->send();
    }
```

I will highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the ajax response.

Comment: @Shivanand when I trying to delete 2nd product the page will redirect to delete page showing message in JSON "Item was removed" ,print all JSON on the page "update_blocks" and page break.  Print ajax response on page like ---->>  {"message":"Item was removed.","update_blocks":[{"key":".header .links","value":"<div class=\"links\"> ....

Comment: Please provide the code in file app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php or app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php and in ajaxDeleteAction function.

Comment: @Shivanand Delete functionality is working fine. Problem only with redirection on delete page on 2nd product delete. I think its related with JS  not with PHP file. What do you think ???

Comment: If you check the remove url with two products, the url action is ajaxDelete. When you click on that url it deleted the product with ajax and reloads the executes minicart block and loads it with ajax. When its done the remove url must have to be like "domain.com/checkout/cart/ajaxDelete/id/29/uenc/xxxxx" not the "SiteURL/checkout/cart/delete/id/012/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyMi". This url will come using the php code.

Comment: @Shivanand For me same `SiteURL/checkout/cart/delete/id/012/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyMi` type of URL generate on both the request like 1. Delete the product by ajax request 2. Delete the product and redirect to delete page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109499/discussion-between-shivanand-and-narayan).

Comment: @Shivanand I got the solution. Please find in Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a solution, its related to a ***Javascript binding problem***. The problem is, when you delete a product from the cart all the cart block gets updated. Hence it removes the already bound javascript.

I have added the javascript bind code at the end of **updateBlocks function** in **ajaxcart.js**.

So, whenever user tries to delete a item from the cart ajax code gets executed and the **response update_blocks** will once again gets bind to the cart even after the initial javascript binding.

Added Javascript bind code is

```
$$('a[href*="/checkout/cart/delete/"]').each(function (e) {    
            $(e).observe('click', function (event) {    
                setLocation($(e).readAttribute('href'));    
                Event.stop(event);    
            });    
        });
```

And after adding code to **ajaxcart.js updateBlocks** function look like ,

```
updateBlocks: function (blocks) {    
        var _this = this;
        if (blocks) {    
            try {    
                blocks.each(function (block) {    
                    if (block.key) {    
                        var dom_selector = block.key;    
                        if ($$(dom_selector)) {    
                            jQuery(block.key, parent.document).each(function (e) {    
                                jQuery(this).html(block.value);    
                            });    
                        }    
                    }    
                });    
                _this.bindEvents();    
                _this.bindNewEvents();    
                // show details tooltip    
                truncateOptions();    
            } catch (e) {    
                console.log(e);    
            }    
        }    
        $$('a[href*="/checkout/cart/delete/"]').each(function (e) {    
            $(e).observe('click', function (event) {    
                setLocation($(e).readAttribute('href'));    
                Event.stop(event);    
            });    
        });    
    }
```